# How do I change tab size for XML files in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I would like to have a tab size for regular text files be '4'. And I know where to set it (Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors: Displayed tab width).

However, for XML files I want to set the tab width to '2'.

I tried `Structural Text Editors`, `Content Types`, `File Associations` to no avail.

I am using the latest version of Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor you can set the indentation size and you can also select whether to use tabs/spaces for indentation.

Comment: Ahhh... Yet another place to look :).  Thanks!

Comment: For the record, this doesn't change the _display_ of the tab width.  It actually changes the number of tabs to use. Going from 1 to 2 will insert 2 tabs instead of 1 when the document is reformatted.

Comment: Under Eclipse Luna for the XML files indentations, when selecting the spaces indentation, the Indentation size cannot be changed, the plus button does not respond. I had to manually edit the workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.prefs file and add the indentationSize=2 entry, and restart Eclipse.